# How to model for word search in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

my model design to save word search from checkbox and it must have update word search and status, delete(fake). my old model set pk is uuid(id of word search) and set index is status (enable, disable, deleted)

but I don't want to set index at status column(I think its very bad to set index at update column) and I don't change database

Is it have better way for model this?

sorry for my english grammar

Comment: Show your current data model. And provide an example

Comment: ex. table(uuid<pk>, category, word_search, status<index>) I want select by status is enable or disable, set index at status is work but I don't do this

Answer (score 0):

**You should not create index on very low cardinality column status**

> Avoid very low cardinality index e.g. index where the number of distinct values is very low. A good example is an index on the gender of an user. On each node, the whole user population will be distributed on only 2 different partitions for the index: MALE & FEMALE. If the number of users per node is very dense (e.g. millions) we’ll have very wide partitions for MALE & FEMALE index, which is bad

Source : https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-native-secondary-index-deep-dive

**Best way to handle this type of case :**

- Create separate table for each type of status
- Or Status with a known parameter (year, month etc) as partition key

Example of 2nd Option

```
CREATE TABLE save_search (
    year int,
    status int,
    uuid uuid,
    category text,
    word_search text,
    PRIMARY KEY((year, status), uuid)
);
```

Here you can see that i have made a composite partition key with `year` and `status`, because of low cardinality issue. If you think huge data will be in a single status then you should also add month as the part of composite partition key

If your dataset is small you can just remove the year field.

```
CREATE TABLE save_search (
    status int,
    uuid uuid,
    category text,
    word_search text,
    PRIMARY KEY(status, uuid)
);
```

Or

If you are using cassandra version 3.x or above then you can use [materialized view](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views)

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW search_by_status AS
    SELECT *
    FROM your_main_table
    WHERE uuid IS NOT NULL AND status IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (status, uuid);
```

You can query with status like :

```
SELECT * FROM search_by_status WHERE status = 0;
```

All the deleting, updating and inserting you made on your main table cassandra will sync it with the materialized view

Comment: how can i update status<pk> and search where clause at status only

Comment: You need to delete and insert again with different status

Comment: @VeerapatBoonvanich by the way if you use timeuuid on uuid field you can extract the time from that uuid and use it on year

Comment: No, You have to specify both year and status. If you think small amount of data will be inserted on each status, you can remove year from the partition key and table.

Comment: @VeerapatBoonvanich can you tell me approximately max how many data can be  with same status ?

Comment: This is very small, you can remove the year from the partition key and table

Comment: i think it have problem, status must update or delete by uuid

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: i think version 3.0

Comment: @VeerapatBoonvanich  Then use materialized view, answer updated

Comment: that new for me

Comment: Check this link https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views